# Is there HAVING statement in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Subject.

Need to filter after GROUP BY.

P.S: I know, Sphinx is not an SQL-storage alternative :-)

Answer (score 1):

Filtering on attribute values can be used to do something equivalent to SQL's having. Look at section 3.3 of the ref man for your version of Sphinx.

I think the manual for recent versions may be out of date where it says that MVAs can only be 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see, Sphinx doesn't have anything like SQL's HAVING statement. Let me know if you find a better answer. I'd be interested.